# RTMP to Browser

Tags: html, rtmp, http-live-streaming, mpeg-dash

I'm looking for a dead-simple way to convert an RTMP stream (from an IP camera) into something I can use in the browser. Ideally this server would read from the `rtmp://` URL of my camera, re-encode the stream, and then server the stream in a format I can use in a `<video>` tag on a web page.

However, my understanding is that HTML5 and the `<video>` tag does not support live streaming. Therefore, I'm left using HLS or DASH. My understanding is that HLS is supported by almost all devices (I only care about the Chrome browser on both my Linux desktop, and my Android device).

So what is the easiest way to convert from a `rtmp://` stream to HLS? I've tried using the `nginx-rtmp-module` (https://github.com/ut0mt8/nginx-rtmp-module), but after re-compiling Nginx, I cannot get the configuration file to work correctly. I also run into the problem that my `rtmp://` URL doesn't seem to fit the "standard" pattern of `rtmp://localhost/$app/$name` I see in most of the documentation. Mine looks like: `rtmp://192.168.1.103:1935/flash/1:YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=` where the last part is a the username and password (admin/admin) encoded in Base64.

Ultimately, I have multiple cameras, and I'm looking to make a simple page where I can display them all. What's the easiest way to go about this on Linux?

Answer (score 2):

For those who might be searching for something similar, I was able to use [ZoneMinder](https://zoneminder.com/). It configures a server that does *exactly* what I want: convert an `RTSP` stream to something that can be displayed in the browser via an `img` tag. You can figure out the URL for the image source by simply inspecting the element in the browser.

The code for the ZoneMinder server is on GitHub: https://github.com/ZoneMinder/zoneminder It would be nice if one could easily extract *just* the server that translates `RTSP` into the image data, but the easiest way to get up-and-going was to simply configure the whole service.

Comment: @DaraJava did you get ZoneMinder working? If so, just inspect the source of the page where the video shows, and then use that URL. It doesn't always work, so I reverted to just using ZoneMinder.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use https://github.com/aler9/rtsp-simple-server. It fulfills your requirement of being “dead simple” and can convert from RTMP to HLS in about 2 to 10 lines of YAML config.